# Rspec not finding routes that exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

I'm trying to write a controller test and Rspec isn't finding routes that I know exist and work fine on a development server.

In my routes I have a catch-all route that should redeirect to a generic controller if someone goes to a route that isn't predefined.

routes.rb

```
namespace :tools do
  match '*unmatchedpath' => "generic#show", :via => :get
end
```

generic_controller.rb

```
def show
  # do stuff
end
```

generic_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Tools::GenericController do

describe 'GET show' do 
  it 'does stuff' do
    get :show
  end
end
```

Here is the error I get from rspec when I run the test above

```
 1) Tools::GenericController GET show does stuff
 Failure/Error: get :show
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"tools/generic", :action=>"show"}
```

All routes work as expected on my development server so I'm not sure why Rspec isn't finding the route.

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and show the output here?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 get '*unmatchedpath' => 'tools/generic#show'
```